# jquery, set focus on the first enabled input or select or textarea on the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, focus

It's fairly straightforward.  I want to set focus to the first enabled and not hidden control on the page.

For a textbox, I have

```
$("input[type='text']:visible:enabled:first").focus();
```

But I want to get "all" form input controls: textbox, checkbox, textarea, dropdown, radio in my selector to grab the first enabled and not hidden control.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
$(':input:enabled:visible:first').focus();
```

Comment: Funny story, I was waiting for the time to elapse so I could select it as the answer, and the power in the office went out.

Comment: I am using a boostrap modal popup and can't get this to work if it is a dropdownlist. Only if it is a textbox, I can use the focus() in codebehind. Any idea why bootstrap modal would not work?

Answer (score 12):

As an extension of Jordan's answer

```
$(':input:enabled:visible:not([readonly]):first').focus();
```

This one also excludes readonly inputs

Answer (score 5):

This is a little more comprehensive:

```
$('form :input:text:visible:not(input[class*=filter]):first').focus();
```

Lamen: Focus the cursor in the first text input in a form that is visible, but if it use the class named "filter", ignore it!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("input[type='text']:enabled","another selector","another selector").first().focus();
```