# How to set the focus on the first <select> element of the page using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to set the focus on the first  element of the page using JQuery when the page is loaded.
I could successfully set the focus for first  element by using

```
$(":input:visible:first").focus();
```

or

```
$(':input:enabled:visible:first').focus();
```

according to [jquery, set focus on the first enabled input or select or textarea on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328381/jquery-set-focus-on-the-first-enabled-input-or-select-or-textarea-on-the-page).

I tried to use any of the below:

```
$('select:first').focus();
$("select").first().focus();
$(':visible:first').focus();
$('enabled:visible:first').focus();
```

or other variations I could think of, but have not succeeded.

Could anyone help me on this problem?
I am a beginner to JQuery.

I would like this function to work for all major browsers.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML in question? Perhaps a formatting issue...? And have you tested this in multiple browsers?

Comment: Also, $(":visible:first") will attempt to focus on whatever the first thing visible is. Probably not what you meant to do. Similarly 'enabled' is not an HTML element, so $("enabled:visible:first") won't point at anything. Keep on trying, it'll come together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is most likely to be that you are not running the code on after the DOM is loaded. Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("select:first").focus();
});
```

That should work.

**EDIT:** You can simplify the code a bit by using this:

```
$(function(){
  $("select:first").focus();
})
```

If you use it that way, jQuery will trigger that function when the document's DOM is ready.

Comment: also make sure that you're including jquery library before you're executing you're own javascript

Comment: sorry about that. I assumed you were including jQuery already. Also, try using Firefox with Firebug, will make your life better.

Comment: Thanks David and Logan for quick reply. However, they do not solve my problems. My code was included in $(document).ready(function(){ }  . Sorry, I didn't explain that.  Also I have included jquery library as <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> .  All those code exists in body part. Since :input:first works, this should be a problem associated with select, I think.  I use this code in Qualtrics, which is an online survey tool like a surveyMonkey. Maybe this is an issue related with that tool..

Comment: Hi. Yes, your code was right. Problem seems like came from other parts of my code. When I cleaned up most of my code and only focused on this function, it worked nicely. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling on element that is not loaded in `DOM`. Place your code in `ready` function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input:visible:first").focus();               
});
```

**UPDATE:**

As seen in @David answer and comments, he is right.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select:first").focus();
});
```

but you have not correctly included jquery (as seen in comment). you have missed to insert **http** before script `src`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adeel, but this does not solve my problem as I mentioned above.