# Set focus on specific select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple select boxes in the pages. I want to set focus on first element of specific select box. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000475/how-to-set-the-focus-on-the-first-select-element-of-the-page-using-jquery) it shows how to set focus on select box. I need to say which one too. I tried below code but it didn't set the focus.

```
$('#thirdDropBox select:first').focus();
```

Comment: Why cant you just: $('#thirdDropBox').focus();? ID's are generally unique to an element.

Comment: What does `#thirdDropBox` refer to? If it is the id for the select box then that is all you need in the selector (i.e. remove the `select:first` part).

Comment: It would definitely help to see some of the HTML ...

Comment: can you put your code in  a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the user to have focus on the first of multiple select's, you can use the following jQuery code:

If you have an id for the first select, you can directly access that element with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#idOfFirstSelect').focus();
});
```

However, if you don't have the id, the following code should work.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/1qo6mxnf/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').first().focus();
});
```

On a separate note, if you also want to have a default option selected, you can set that option to "selected" in the HTML:

```
<option value="saab" selected="selected">Saab</option>
```

Comment: Great answer but if it literally is just the first "select" on the page with an ID. Then the above is overkill. Good answer though :)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, if you have an id, you can directly specify that id in the selector.  However, if you don't have the id, this should work.

Comment: I certainly agree. Worth mentioning in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery selector:

```
$('#thirdDropBox select:first')
```

will select the first "select" html element that is a descendant of an html-element that has an ID-attribute with the value "thirdDropBox".

For more information see: http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

You probably need to remove the '#thirdDropBox"-part from your selector:

```
$('select:first')
```