# set the focus to <select> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form for sign up, the first `element` is the `textbox` and the second `element` is the `select`.

When I press the Enter key, i want the focus set at the `select` element.

```
$('#newUserId').keypress(function(event){
    if (event.which == 13)
    $('#newUserId:first').focus();
});
```

I have also looked around, and even [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000475/how-to-set-the-focus-on-the-first-select-element-of-the-page-using-jquery) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388472/set-focus-on-specific-select-box) does not help, when i press enter key, it does nothing. but when I check to set the focus on other `textbox` element, it did change focus.

My HTML Form:

```
<form name='formCreateNewUser' id='formCreateNewUser' method='post' action=''>
        <label> Create New User </label> <br />
           <input autocomplete='off' name='newUserId' id='newUserId' class='newUser' 
              type='text' size='17' maxlength='17' placeholder='ID No.' 
        /> <span id='newUserIdResult'> </span><br /><br />
        <select name='newUserType' id='newUserType' class='newUser'>
           <option class='newUser' value=0>User Type</option>
           <option class='newUser' value=1>Student</option>
           <option class='newUser' value=2>Teacher</option>
           <option class='newUser' value=5>Admin</option>
        </select> <br /><br />
        <input autocomplete='off' name='newUserPass' id='newUserPass' class='newUser' 
            size='17' maxlength='17' placeholder='Password' type='password' 
        /> <br /><br />
        <input autocomplete='off' name='newUserConfPass' id='newUserConfPass' class='newUser' 
           size='17' maxlength='17' placeholder='Confirm Password' type='password' 
        /> <br /><br />
        <input autocomplete='off' name='newUserFirstName' id='newUserFirstName' class='newUser' 
           size='17' maxlength='17' placeholder='First Name' type='text' 
        /> <br /><br />
        <input autocomplete='off' name='newUserMiddleName' id='newUserMiddleName' class='newUser' 
           size='17' maxlength='17' placeholder='Middle Name' type='text' 
        /> <br /><br />
        <input autocomplete='off' name='newUserLastName' id='newUserLastName' class='newUser' 
           size='17' maxlength='17' placeholder='Last Name' type='text' 
        /> <br /><br />
        <button name='newUserSubmit' id='newUserSubmit' class='operationstylebutton' type='button' >Create User</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wn8nos2/3/) added a class for highlighting effect

```
$('#newUserId').keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13)
    {$('#newUserType').addClass("highlght").focus();}
});
```

Comment: your answer worked, can you explain why my solution did not? When I look at the answer, it is almost similar to what I have written. Tnx

Comment: You were selecting `#newUserId` instead of `#newUserType`

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/o11vowsp/

```
$('#newUserId').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 )
    $('#newUserType').focus();
});
```