# How to set focus on first form element in any bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select dropdown list and 2 input fields. I know how to set focus on first input field for ANY modal using :

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).find('input:text:visible:first').focus();
})
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDG195P90CWU

But I can't see how to do when there are both dropdown lists and input fields.

Comment: So when you load the modal do you want the select to be focused?

Comment: @pasquers yes but if it is the first element

Comment: So I may not completely understand the requirements, but I believe this would do what you want: 

     .modal-body > select:first, .modal-body > input:first

That way, regardless of if its a select or input if its the first element it will be chosen. Only requirement is it has to be the direct child

Comment: @pasquers I think so thanks, will try (I'm beginner)

Comment: this is not actually working when the select isn't present because the input isn't a direct descendant, I'll have to re think through this

Comment: @pasquers ah ok so it's not obvious :)

Comment: Okay updated answer: .modal-body > select:first-child, .modal-body > div.form-group:first-child input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this: `$("select:first").focus();`

Here is the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });

  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    //$(this).find('input:text:visible:first').focus();
    $("select:first").focus();
  })

});
```

When you run it you can see the select box is highlighted blue (at least in Chrome it is) I found this answer based on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000475/how-to-set-the-focus-on-the-first-select-element-of-the-page-using-jquery). Hope that helps

**EDIT**:

If you want it to select either the first text or select field you can use:

```
$(this).find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible:first').focus();
```

If you need it to look for additional input fields (like `password` or `radio button`) you will need to add them in the `find` list. Another [similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823471/jquery-how-to-find-first-visible-input-select-textarea-excluding-buttons).

Comment: I think they want either a select or an input to both be covered by one set of styles

Comment: @pasquers tried crazymatt solution seems to work, will try yours also

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution developed on top of that by @craztmatt and others. I have extended to have the selection of the target element start at the modal that triggered the event.

```
// do this to make bootstrap modals auto-focus.
// delegate to body so that we only have to set it up once.
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var ele = $(e.target).find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible:first'); // find the first input on the bs modal
    if (ele) {ele.focus();} // if we found one then set focus.
})
```