# Apply :first to multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, focus

I'm wondering if this is possible.

I have a web page and I want to focus on the first, enabled, visible, field in a form.  The first field could be an Input Field OR a select field.  I have tried (with JQuery) the following format

```
input,select:visible:enabled:first
```

and also

```
(input,select):visible:enabled:first
```

but neither of these appear to work for me.

So can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate question Here's the answer to your issue: [jquery, set focus on the first enabled input or select or textarea on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328381/jquery-set-focus-on-the-first-enabled-input-or-select-or-textarea-on-the-page)

Comment: You are correct Franky.  I managed to miss this soultion when I was searching. Sorry.  The solution that works best for me is :input:visible:enabled:first.  I had missed the leading ':' off of input.

Comment: @BoltClock: my reputation can't allow me to flag as duplicate!

Comment: @Franky: You only need 15 reputation to raise a flag. See http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts What you don't have yet is the privilege to cast close votes, however you can still flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @BoltClock ok thanks I'll remember next time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('input,select').filter(':visible:enabled:first')` sounds like it'll do what you want.

This is untested, and I'm a little wary of how the `:first` will behave tacked on there, so if that doesn't work, you can always do:

```
$('input,select').filter(':visible:enabled').first();
```

Comment: This is why I hate how jQuery borrows from CSS syntax and munges its own rules into existing, familiar syntax for what it calls "filter selectors".

Comment: There is also a ":input" selector which will save you from having to say "input,select" and will cover other things like radio boxes as well.

Comment: @Slider345: That too, although it can't be used if one specifically only wants inputs and selects.

Comment: @BoltClock ~ I hear ya; I've never actually been really comfortable using `:first` and `:last` (and similar pseudos) in my own code. I keep getting paranoid that they won't behave as expected.

Comment: Sorry, need to refresh more!  Slider345's solution (which is the same as Franky's) works perfectly for me.  I don't need to distinguish between inptus and radio buttons etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `filter` selector:

```
$("input,select").filter(":visible:enabled:first");
```